# Change the Class attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js

D3 learner here. I am trying to select all elements with particular class (lets say "move"), trigger some events on some of those elements (when clicked color changes). Now I want to assign a new class to those elements (say "hasmoved") on which event was triggered i.e. which were clicked

Here is my trial. But it doesn't work

```
d3.selectAll(".move")               
.on("click", function() {
d3.select(this)
           .classed("hasmoved",true) 
          .style("fill","rgba(48,63,43,0.5)")
    .attr("transform",'translate(700)')})


d3.selectAll(".hasmoved")
.on("click", function() {
        d3.select(this)    
        .style("fill","pink")})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proper indentation will help here:

```
d3.selectAll(".move")
  .on("click", function() {
    d3.select(this)
      .classed("hasmoved", true)
      .style("fill", "rgba(48,63,43,0.5)")
      .attr("transform", 'translate(700)')
  });

d3.selectAll(".hasmoved")
  .on("click", function() {
    d3.select(this)
      .style("fill", "pink")
  });
```

As we can see, the `d3.selectAll(".hasmoved").on(//etc...` block is outside the first `on` method. Therefore, that block will run immediately, in a moment when there is no `hasmoved` class anywhere, since the user has not clicked anything yet.

The easier solution is just setting the `on` method to each clicked element:

```
d3.selectAll(".move")
  .on("click", function() {
    d3.select(this)
      .classed("hasmoved", true)
      .style("fill", "rgba(48,63,43,0.5)")
      .attr("transform", 'translate(700)')
      .on("click", function() {
        d3.select(this)
          .style("fill", "pink")
      });
  });
```